# 'ng-click' in select options

Tags: angularjs

I have ready model to use with `ng-click`:

```
<ul ng-show="bulkMode =='main'">
<li><div class="clickable" ng-click="bulkMode = 'add'">Add</div></li>
<li><div class="clickable" ng-click="bulkMode = 'remove'">Remove</div></li>
</ul>
```

I want to If I check option in select with `value="add"` It will do the same like `ng-click="bulkMode = 'add'"` etc.

How should I do?

Comment: How would you show your list if you set the value of `bulkMode` to  Add or remove because ng-show says only show when bulkMode is main

Comment: Has `bulkMode` been initialised? Either in the controller or using `ng-init`.. @ZohaibIjaz Makes a good point in that clicking one of the options would hide them, is that the desired behaviour?

Comment: bulkMode initialised. I want to do like this:
    <select>
    <option ng-click="bulkMode = 'add'">Add</option>
    <option ng-click="bulkMode = 'remove'">Add</option>
    </select>
Of course if it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Look this example for this: https://github.com/axel-zarate/js-custom-select

Use the method onSelect for change your object.

Running: http://jseppi.github.io/angular-dropdowns/

Answer (score 0):

bulkMode was initialised. I want to do like this:

```
<select>
<option ng-click="bulkMode = 'add'">Add</option>
<option ng-click="bulkMode = 'remove'">Add</option>
<option ng-click="bulkPublish()">Publish</option>
</select>
```

Of course if it is possible